# Strawberry Perl: forgets environment variables?

Tags: windows, perl, environment-variables, perl-module, strawberry-perl

I've installed a number of modules into my Strawberry Perl running on Windows XP, such as:

- Regexp::Common
- URI::Find::Schemeless

These libraries work fine in my perl code the first time directly after installing each module.

**The problem is that every subsequent day I run my scripts they fail** with the error:

> Can't locate Regexp/Common.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:/strawberry/perl/lib C:/ strawberry/perl/site/lib C:\strawberry\perl\vendor\lib .)

I have put all the appropriate paths into environment variables into Windows: PERL5LIB and others such as lib that were suggested on various other answers on stackoverflow and other wesites dealing with module installations.
The scripts continue to fail unless I perform the following workaround that I figured out:

1. Open the "edit the environment variables" window in Windows. ("My Computer" -> "Properties" -> "Advanced" tab -> "Environment Variables")
2. Without adding or changing anything, click OK.
3. Re-open any perl consoles that were already open or open a new perl window.
4. Now the libraries are all found without issues.

Does anyone have an idea why this might be happening? I suspect it may be something specifically related to Windows/cmd or even my company's windows environment setup?

Any suggestions would be appreciated because it is an extremely annoying problem!

Comment: If this is a corporate computer, I wouldn't be surprised to find out there's a System Management Service script running daily to revert certain environment changes.  If that's the case, then you may need to wrap your perl scripts in a batch file that explicitly sets these variables before invoking the perl script with `set PERL5LIB=whatever` etc.

Comment: What does `echo %PERL5LIB%` print when run in your Perl console?

Comment: @cjm - it says c:\strawberry\lib;c:\strawberry\c\lib;c:\strawberry\perl\lib;c:\strawberry\perl\site\lib;c:\strawberry\perl\vendor\lib
which is where the libraries are.
It says this after I do the little "workaround" too. It's really weird!

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?  I found reports of this happening at least on Vista (http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/windows-vista-forgets-my-path-environment-variable-reboot-t3191291.html), so it's not a completely unique problem, but I didn't find a solution.  In any case, it's not a programming problem, so it doesn't belong on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows does not clear the environment variables daily by default, therefore it's likely something in your corporate settings resetting the environment variables.

If this is the case, you have a few options:

1. Get the network admins to modify the script so that it doesn't reset them (or includes the `PERL5LIB` directories you want to specify).
2. Write another daily task, running after their daily task, which re-adds the variables on your local machine.
3. Wrap your perl scripts with a Windows batch file, or run them with `perl -I` to specify the library at run time.
4. Run your perl scripts from Cygwin bash or mingw bash, which won't use your computer's global environment variables.